# Editing Jekyll index.html

Tags: python, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to change my github pages Jekyll index.html

```
--- layout: default ---
{% for post in site.posts %}
{{ post.title }}
{{ post.excerpt }} 
Read More 
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
--- layout: default ---
{% for post in site.posts %}
{{ post.title }}
{{content}} 
Read More 
{% endfor %}
```

so the entire post shows up on the homepage.

When I run jekyll serve I don't get what I want

[image: pic]

However, the strange thing is that when I edit the index.html back to it's original content, I still get the wrong output

[image: pic2]

Editing the index.html in my Jekyll folder is breaking everything, what's going on?  The only way I can get the site to work again is to delete index.html and replace it with a copy of the original.

I should point out that the index.html file I'm editing is the same folder that contains the _site, _posts folders.

Comment: Try to build your site first using this command ``jekyll build --watch`` from the terminal.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work

Comment: Try putting the `---` on separate lines.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work

Comment: Make sure that you have all required gem packages installed by issuing this command in your jekyll site folder : 
``gem install``.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem!

Instead of using gedit or vim, like a novice I used TextEdit.  If you type '---' in TextEdit you'll observe that it converts the first two dashes into a single long dash character (although in the screen caps it still looks like 3 dashes...)

Switching to vim fixed it.

Update:  Out of curiosity I edited index.html in TextEdit, then opened it in vim.  The file was completely different, so TextEdit introduces more significant changes then altering a few dashes.

Comment: For future reference, you can use TextEdit in plain text mode to avoid those changes, press shift+command+T as soon as you launch it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Jekyll Docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/), your front matter should be surrounded by `---` on separate lines. Your file likely isn't being parsed since it is all on a single line, try this instead:

```
---
layout: default
---
{% for post in site.posts %}
{{ post.title }}
{{content}} 
Read More 
{% endfor %}
```